# [attribute="value"] Jquery не заполняет

Tags: jquery, input

Добрый день.

Есть у меня такой input:

```
<input type="text" name="test[test]" value="" />
```

И скрипт Jquery:

```
<script>$('input[name="test[test]"]').val('TES!');</script>
```

Вроде скрипт должен работать и заполнять поле. Но не работает. Как сделать, чтоб заполняло `name="test[test]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже догадался, как сделать, чтоб работало:

```
<script>$('input[name='test[test]']').val('TES!');</script>
```

Comment: И оно у вас с такими кавычками работает?? Что за магия??

Comment: Ваш код: `$('input[name='test[test]']').val('TES!');`
не может работать по определению!

Comment: Будет синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: Вот как он работает 

$("input[name='test[test]']").val('test');

Answer (score 2):

Замени свой скрипт на такой блок кода и будет работать:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="test[test]"]').val('TES!');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Код правильный. Дайте контекст, желательно весь каркас страницы (тег html, head, body), какой подключен jq и подключился ли он, где располагается скрипт.

Возможные причины:

- Скрипт находится до поля ввода. Тогда он выполнится до загрузки поля и, естественно, ничего не произойдет. Оберните его в `$(window).load(function(){...});`.
- JQ подключен неверно. Откройте консоль и посмотрите ошибки.